# IIS7 and clientCaching with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, caching

Is it possible to declaratively set `clientCache` for an Action using the web.config in IIS7?

We need to set an expiry value of 1 day for our `Home/Index` action. As of now we are doing this using a filter attribute. Is it possible to accomplish the same declaratively?

We are able to do it for static content, but not for action methods through the `location` and `system.webServer` sections in the web.config.

```xml
<location path="Content">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache httpExpires="Sat, 28 Nov 2009 09:00:00 GMT" cacheControlMode="UseExpires" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would be possible to do so in web.config - we create a base controller and put it in there.  That way we don't have to decorate all of our actions with attributes.